# Wordpress: How to combine keyword search and meta filter in WP_query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to combine the search by keyword and meta_key and meta_value filter in WP_query. Keyword search and meta filter works good independently, but together are not. How to get it done? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['search']) AND $_REQUEST['search'] )
{
    $query_param = array( 's' => urldecode($_REQUEST['search']), 'post_type' => GOODS_POST_TYPE );
    $query_param['meta_key'] = 'sku';
    $query_param['meta_value'] = urldecode($_REQUEST['search']);
}
$query = new WP_Query($query_param);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query before the search is run, and use Wordpress' built-in functions to do what you need rather than relying on unfiltered data:

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_goods_search');
function modify_goods_search($query)
{
    if($query->is_search)
    {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'sku');
        $query->set('meta_value', get_search_query());
        $query->set('post_type', GOODS_POST_TYPE);
    }
}
?>
```

Remember that this will modify ALL searches. If you want to modify only one particular search, you can modify the conditional to make sure you're on a particular page before modifying the given query.

You might also want to consider using meta_query rather than just meta_key and meta_value.

Information on everything:

[Pre Get Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)
[Custom Field Parameters in Meta Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)
[Get Search Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_query)